# Benefit of using createSelector when there is only one parent selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js, reselect

Suppose we have a simple redux store:

```
{
  user: {
    age: 10
  }
}
```

And we have a selector to get user:

```
const getUser = state => state.get('user')     // suppose we used immutable.js
```

now we have two approaches to get user age:

1. use `createSelector` and use getUser as parent selector:

```
const getAge = createSelector(
   getUser,
   user => user.get('age')
)
```

2. use existing selector directly:

```
const getAge = state => getUser(state).get('age');
```

Question:

**Which one is better, regarding performance, memorization, etc.**

Another derived question:

The example I proposed here is very simple, let's consider when it comes to a very **large and complicate** redux store, will the difference of two approaches matter?

Answer (score 1):

If the selector's properties change often, it would make sense to keep them on separate selectors. At least in the case of selectors where usually the object changes as a whole, I prefer to create one selector for the user.

As an example, let's say we have the object:

```
const profile = {
  name   : 'John',
  email,
  timezone,
  ...
  locale : 'en',
}
```

If a `<Translate>` component is created that is tightly coupled to the locale, but not to other parts of the profile such as name, etc., then a selector for `getLocale()` makes sense (and is how we implement our locale component).

On the other side, if you have a Profile Page where users can edit various fields, then that page most likely needs to re-render frequently when changes are made, so it would make sense to just have a `getProfile()` selector on that page.

We handle a quite complex and large Redux state, and for example, because we use the `currentUserId`, or `userName` all over the place in our web application, we have dedicated selectors for these to take advantage of memoization.

But, for a quiz or assignment, we use a single selector `getQuizContents()` instead of its internal fields, as we know that most components that need information about a quiz, don't need just the name but many internal fields such as date, number of questions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand for simple consistense and primitive results you shouldn't use `createSelector` at all, use it for expensive calculation only or when the new result is not shallow equal the old one.

- example when you shouldn't use memoization:

`export const getUserIds = state => state.ids; // always the same array`

- example when you should use memoization:

`export const getUserIds = state => state.ids.map(id => id.toString) -- every time the new array because of map fn`

Your code is returning simple raw values, so you don't need any memoization.

Fix me somebody if I am wrong